# Javascript Object to Json. PHP can't decode serialized JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a javascript object which I am encoding to Json and sending data to PHP. Unfortunately, PHP can't decode JSON string to array. I am lost at this point.

**Jquery**

```
sendData = {city: 48, fullName: 'John'};
sendData = JSON.stringify(sendData);

$.get("ajax/getter.php", { get: "info", data: sendData },function(data){
   // DO STH with returned data
});
```

**OUTPUT :** `{"city":48,"fullName":"John"}`

**PHP part**

```
<?php 
$data  = $_GET['data'];
$data = json_decode($data);
var_dump($data);
?>
```

**OUTPUT :** `NULL`

I will be glad if anyone could show me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: var_dump($_GET) to see what you have there.

Comment: json_decode returns null if the data could not be decoded.  I suspect there is some url encoding issues.  Can you var_dump($_GET['data']); and see what the output is?  There may be escaped characters or url encoded characters that need to be unescaped/decoded.

Comment: What is printing json_last_error() ?

Comment: Did you call var_dump($data); *before* running json_decode() to make sure you are actually getting the string representation?

Comment: I am so embarrassed right now. I have no idea how did I do such mistake and didn't realize for 2-3 hours I did check everything but forgot just one thing!!! My security class was doing a filtering to all $_GET and $_POST. Once I did necessary changes everything went back to normal. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must have [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/magic_quotes_gpc) enabled and in `$_GET['data']`, all `"` chars are escaped.

Disable [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/magic_quotes_gpc). If you can't, use [`stripslashes`](http://php/net/stripslashes):

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['data']))
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. This must be the problem. To make the code portable, do `if(function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc()){ stripslashes($_GET['data']);}`

Comment: get_magic_quotes_gpc exists since PHP4, I think you can assume it exists :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. After reading your comment, I remembered about my security class (which is filtering all $_GET and $_POST). Once I did necessary changes, everything went back to normal. I guess sometimes such things happen (happens a lot to me lately, I guess I need to rest more)