# CKEditor " and \" magic quote issue

Tags: php, javascript, gmail, ckeditor

I have a problem with CKEditor. When I try to add a link with it

```
<a href="foo.html">foo</a>
```

it always replaces " with \"

```
<a href=\"foo.html\">foo</a>
```

This kind of notation seems like working when I print it on a page but if I e-mail it with a php script, gmail renders it like

```
<a>foo</a>
```

Can anyone have an idea about that?

Can I achieve this with config.js?

Note: This is not about the mailer php script because I have tested it without CKEditor.

UPDATE: I have [disabled the magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) in my php script and working properly.

Comment: You have magic_quotes_gpc enabled. 
See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449105/javascript-object-to-json-php-cant-decode-serialized-json/7449168#7449168

Comment: Please disable javascript and submit the html code plain-text. You still see the `\"`? If so, that's magic quotes. Disable it.

Comment: thank you guys. disabling magicquote in php solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid disabling magic_quotes for example for a shared server i have used (caus i had a problem in mailto link converted to \ )

> stripslashes($text)

or as i have found in php.net [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)  example #2

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```